# No database provider has been configured for this DbContext in ASP.NET Core 2.1

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-6, asp.net-core-2.1

I get this error:

> InvalidOperationException: No database provider has been configured for this DbContext. A provider can be configured by overriding the DbContext.OnConfiguring method or by using AddDbContext on the application service provider. If AddDbContext is used, then also ensure that your DbContext type accepts a DbContextOptions object in its constructor and passes it to the base constructor for DbContext.

I tried everything, but right again. I want to define the startup connection string, but I can not.

My `ApplicationDbContext` is:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : DbContext
{
    public ApplicationDbContext(){}
    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options): base(options){}

    public DbSet<Course> Courses { get; set; }
    public DbSet<CourseType> CourseTypes { get; set; }
    public DbSet<CourseState> CourseStates { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Topic> Topics { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Heding> Hedings { get; set; }
}
```

My StartUp is :

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
     services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);
    services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DbLearning"))));
}
```

My `appSetting.json` is :

```
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DbLearning": "Server=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Database=DbLearning;Trusted_Connection=True;"
  }
```

The problem is that in startUp but in `onConfiguring` not problem

Comment: What is the serviceProvider in your AddDbContext?

Comment: removed it and change code

Comment: And you have exact the same error?

Comment: Yes, exactly :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
        options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DbLearning")));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the most known way using localdb

Code in appsetting.json

```
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DbLearning": "Server=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Database=DbLearning;Trusted_Connection=True;"
  }
```

Code in Startup.cs

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
        options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DbLearning")));
}
```

Comment: I tested not worked for me .
Again, I saw Error and did not care

Comment: What Server do you have installed in your machine.

Comment: LocalDb is installed in your machine?

Comment: visual 2017 , sql 2017

Answer (score 0):

```
"ConnectionStrings": {
  "DbLearning": "Server=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Database=DbLearning;Trusted_Connection=True;"
}
```

Comment: Please add some comments as to how this code resolves the question in order to improve this answer.